# Difference between core_abstract_delete_after and core_abstract_delete_commit_after events in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2, event-observer, abstract-class

Can anyone please explain to me what is the use of **core_abstract_delete_after** and **core_abstract_delete_commit_after** events in magento 2.

For your information, it is declared in (**Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel**) this abstract class.

If it is possible so please let me know how can I test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving happens in a MySQL transaction and the **delete_after** event is triggered before the transaction is committed, so that you can do additional updates in the database within the same transaction.

The **delete_commit_after** event is triggered after the transaction has been committed, i.e. when the changes were written to the database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I have one more question - Are both events call on any MySQL transaction?

Comment: @deexiysanghani yes both are called MySql transaction one is before other is after.